# Visual Query Builder From TreeView Control

Tags: c#, treeview, where-clause, query-builder

I want to create a sql query builder which can build where clause from an n level TreeView control as you can see below.

[Sample TreeView Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYGcs.png)

result should be; **(**Age = 36 AND Name = 'Jack' AND (City = 'Newyork' OR City = 'California')**)**

is there any simple way to do it? I worked on it so hard but couldn't do it because of lack of my knowledge.

Comment: Why a treeview? Start with just drop down boxes of field names and textboxes for input. When you get that working maybe you could move it to tree view. Remember sql queries should always use parameters and not concatenate strings.

Comment: hi Mary. because I want to build nested and complex queries. Thanks for your reply. 

Comment: this can help if you looking for same question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34351846/build-sql-query-from-treeview-nodes?rq=4